# object name is same as variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have an object

```
const myArray = {
   a : "hello"
}
```

and I have a string with the same name of that object
like

```
var type ="myArray";
```

when I do `console.log(type);`

```
output: myArray
```

but I want to out that object to the console which has the same name as the value of variable type.
How should I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's a global variable, it will be stored in `window`.

So, you can do something like `console.log(window[type])` to access to value.

Comment: Thank you but I already got the answer. Its using eval().